# tfs agent build required files

Tags: tfs, msbuild

How can I set tfs build on agent to use one location for following files?

I have couple files that are run on after build of specific project.
files:

- SomeFile.exe
- RequiredDll.exe

I am using it for creating custom setups files, that is done from SomeFile.exe.
Now every time I have project that I want to run the actions, I need to copy files above into the project, which I know is wrong.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put these files in a common location within Source Control.  Then in your build configuration you can map that common folder to a working folder for the build.

This is named slightly differently in the different versions of Visual Studio.  In all versions it is found when editing a build configuration.

**Visual Studio 2008 / 2010**

- Workspace

**Visual Studio 2012**

- Source Settings

This allows you to map a source control folder to the Build Agents working build folder.  You will then be able to access the same exe's in all your builds and they will only be in Source Control once.

A common practice is to have a Team Project dedicated to build artifacts. Then in your mappings you have something like this:

<kbd>Status</kbd><kbd>Source Control Folder</kbd><kbd>Build Agent Folder</kbd>              
<kbd>Active</kbd><kbd>$/BuildProject/lib</kbd>         <kbd>$(SourceDir)\BuildArtifacts</kbd>